# THREE.Object3D: .eulerOrder is now .rotation.order

Tags: three.js

I set `{Object3D}.eulerOrder = 'YZX';` and then rotate the object with `{Object3D}.rotation.set(...)`, and I get the following warning: *"THREE.Object3D: .eulerOrder is now .rotation.order."*.

I tried changing the `{Object3D}.rotation.order` to all the different permutations, but the warning remains.

https://jsfiddle.net/mocdo0h7/

Comment: Please demonstrate the problem with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: @Mugen87 https://jsfiddle.net/mocdo0h7/

Comment: @Mugen87 is this my fault for not fully understanding how this works and doing something silly? Or is this a bug? I saw you commit some code on github today (all I saw was the title about shaders). Did that resolve this issue?

Comment: No, that was something different ;). The following code does not work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/mocdo0h7/2/ The warning is gone in any case.

Comment: @Mugen87 oi ve! It does work. I read on multiple places to change `eulerOrder`. Thanks.

Comment: @Mugen87 if you submit answer however brief I will accept. thanks for helping rid the warning.

Answer (score 1):

kudos to @Mugen87

answer: use `rotation.order` instead of `eulerOrder`